# java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index, even when I provide correct number of parameter

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm getting the error `java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3` when I run the following code. I've checked the parameters, its only 2 and I used only 2 in the `PreparedStament`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    JsonObject projectObject = projectQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject obj = projectObject.getAsJsonObject();
    //System.out.println(obj);
    projectValue = getJsonValue(obj, "_refObjectName");
    System.out.println(projectValue);
    objectValue = getJsonValue(obj, "ObjectID");
    System.out.println(objectValue);

    //st.("INSERT INTO CUST_RALLY_PROJECT_OBJID Values('" + projectValue + "','" + objectValue + "')");

    updateString += "update odf_ca_other ";
    updateString += "set rallyid = ? ";
    updateString += "where id = (select inv.id from inv_investments inv, odf_ca_other oco where inv.id = oco.id and inv.odf_object_code = 'other' and inv.name = ? ";
    updateString += "AND ( oco.team_type = 'delivery_team' or oco.team_type = 'reg_team' or oco.team_type = 'ux_team' or oco.team_type = 'business_team')) ";

    PreparedStatement rs = conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
    rs.setString(1, objectValue);
    rs.setString(2, projectValue);
    rs.execute();
    conn.commit();
}
```

Comment: Try to `close` the stmt, first before reusing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `updateString` outside of the loop, but in every loop you are concatenating in it, so in the first iteration it is fine (has two parameters), but in the second it has 4, then 6 and so on.

You need to:

1. Define the query string (`updateString`) outside of the loop
2. Prepare the query once (also outside of the loop)

Preparing the query once also has a performance benefit, because the statement is not unprepared and reprepared on each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

```
updateString = "";
```

You have to empty it before the next iteration.

Else, define it once, outside the loop and just reuse it inside loop. as @mark mentioned in comment!

Comment: Better yet: define the statement outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 updateString += "update odf_ca_other ";
 updateString += "set rallyid = ? ";
 updateString += "where id IN (select inv.id from inv_investments inv, odf_ca_other oco where inv.id = oco.id and inv.odf_object_code = 'other' and inv.name = ? ";
 updateString += "AND ( oco.team_type = 'delivery_team' or oco.team_type = 'reg_team' or oco.team_type = 'ux_team' or oco.team_type = 'business_team')) ";
```

Try to change `id =`  for `id in`. It should solve your problem.